# In iOS tutorial, "Property toDoItems not found on object type of XYZToDoListViewController"

Tags: ios, xcode

I was going through Apple's [XCode tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1) and I've reached an error I cannot diagnose.

This is the relevant part of `XYZToDoListViewController.m`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    XYZToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;

    return cell;
}
```

So it's telling me that `Property toDoItems not found on object type of XYZToDoListViewController` but that makes no sense because in the `XYZToDoListViewController.h` imports a header file `XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h` that has `toDoItems` declared as a nonatomic property.

Proabably just a stupid mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing a header doesn't mean that your class will inherit the properties from imported header class. You should **declare** a `toDoItems` array in your `XYZToDoListViewController` class and fill it with objects of `XYZToDoItem` type.

So you should have something like this in your `XYZToDoListViewController.m` file:

**Declaration**:

```
@interface XYZToDoListViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end

...
```

**Allocation/initialization**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

*Note*:
Don't forget to fill `toDoItems` array with `XYZToDoItem`s.